# Help with sum of a series of fractions

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, limits

I was expected to have this series $$S = \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{k}} $$
summed up to 1. However, I couldn't do that using this calculation:
$$ S = \frac{1}{2} + S - \frac{1}{2} $$ where $$ \frac{1}{2} + S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{3}} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{k}} $$ was a geometric series.
Thus, $$ S = \frac{1}{2} + S - \frac{1}{2} = a(\frac{1 - r^{k}}{1 -r}) - \frac{1}{2} $$
where $ a = \frac{1}{2} $, and $ r = \frac{1}{2} $.

Substituting the values of $a$ and $r$ into the expression above, I got $$ S = \frac{2^k - 1}{2^k} - \frac{1}{2} $$
Then taking limit on the right hand side $$ \lim_{k \to \infty} (\frac{2^k - 1}{2^k} - \frac{1}{2}) $$
I got $$ S = \frac{1}{2} $$
What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**: The reason I wanted to have $S$ summed to 1 because of this requirement (highlighted in yellow):

[image]

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong, your series actually sums to $\frac{1}{2}$ when $k$ approaches infinity

Comment: If your series were to start at $1/2^1$ and extend to infinity, then it'd sum to $1$. But without that, it just sums to $1/2$ as indicated.

Comment: Your solution is completely correct. It could have been a little shorter if you do not add and subtract $\frac{1}{2}$ and  directly see that it is a geometric series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are two cases for each case containing $k$ letters (e.g. for 2 letters: aa,bb; for 3 letters: acc, bcc). So the probability of all the cases actually sum to $$2\cdot \frac{1}{2^2}+2\cdot \frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots =\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots =\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}=1$$

Comment: Thanks. Why did I fail to notice that obvious fact?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} r^k=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$
Here
$$S = \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{3}} + \frac{1}{2^{4}}... + \frac{1}{2^{k}} $$
$$S=\frac{1}{2^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{k-2}}\right)$$
$$S=\frac{1}{4}\frac{2^{-(k-1)}-1}{2^{-1}-1}=\frac{1}{2}(1-2^{1-k})$$
So if $k\to \infty$, $S\to \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the succinct calculation, Ahmed. I have edited the OP to emphasise  the requirement of $S$ should be summed to 1.